# how to randomly change a probability?

Tags: java, random, numbers, probability

I have a collection of double values, each representing a probability (i.e. [0-1] range).

I want to add an uniformly distributed noise to these values. The values, after the modification, must still represent probabilities ([0-1] range).

Additionally, I want to be able to specify a desired range for the perturbation independently for each value: for some probabilities i would like to modify them by a small percentage and for others I would like to change them by a large percentage.

I'm unsure about how to proceed: I can only imagine swapping probabilities between different items.

I have considered to use java.Util.Random but I dont see any methods I can use.

Can anyone illustrate a possible algorithm to achieve this?

Comment: [`java.util.Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html)

Comment: A few comments in one: (a) a probability is always in [0,1], (b) if you have a single value, what do you mean by "swapping"? and (c) if the modification is value-dependent, can you specify how?

Comment: have you considered actually doing it yourself?

Comment: Math.random() is random enough. It does not make sense to me make a random number "more" random or "less" random.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because @OP admits having no clue how to implement

Comment: I did edit my question. I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: I dont see anything in java.util.random that will help me edit a double

Comment: @RegUser Nope, it's still not clear. Did you consider adding some examples. What you expect and what you did?

Comment: See my answer and let me know if my interpretation of your question is correct. If so, I'll edit your question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to add a random, uniformly distributed noise to a set of values (which are probabilities, and therefore must remain between 0 and 1).

Suppose your original value is:

```
double myProbability;
```

and you want to add an uniform noise with max range:

```
double desiredDelta;
```

You can, at most, vary it such that it doesn't become > 1 or < 0:

```
double maxDelta = Math.min(myProbability, 1-myProbability);
```

At this point, you need to define what the actual range of your noise will be:

```
double actualDelta = Math.min(desiredDelta, maxDelta);
```

Now you need to either add or remove a random value between 0 and actualDelta:

```
boolean noiseIsAdded = Math.random() > 0.5; //50% prob add, 50% prob subtract
double noise = Math.random() * actualDelta; //scales down the 0-1 range to 0-actualDelta

double newProbability;
if (noiseIsAdded) newProbability = myProbability + noise;
else newProbability = myProbability - noise;
```

And you should have it.

Comment: @RegUser I modified your question, my edits will be visible after (if) approved by the peer review. Please notice that I coded this example assuming "desiredDelta" is an absolute value, not a percentage of the original one. You'll need to change a couple of things if you want a percentage, but it should be trivial.

Comment: Thank you. By controlling desiredDelta I can control how much noise is added?

Comment: You can control the maximum DESIRED range in both directions (+/-). I say desired because, suppose that your original value is 0.75 , and you desire to add a range of 0.5, you can't just add it directly, because you risk to go above 1 and not be a probability anymore. You need to cap it to the maximum allowed range (ofc, you could have asymmetric ranges for + and -, but that's another story and you still need to cap both)